# How to save and add a value obtained in the game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a store for my game and I'm making a system where the score I get in the game is saved and every time you play it adds and saves too, but this last part isn't working I don't know why, I'm taking a variable from another script called `score` it receives the value I got and had to add it to the previous value but it doesn't happen.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
    
public class CoinsManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject YellowSquare;
    private int totalScore;
    
    void Start() 
    {      
        YellowSquare.GetComponent<Text>().text = GameController.score.ToString();
        totalScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("lastScore", GameController.score);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        SaveMoney();
    } 
    
    void SaveMoney()
    {
        totalScore = GameController.score++;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("lastScore", totalScore);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a question about using the Visual Studio application so I have removed the `[visual-studio]` tag. Likewise, this code is written in the C# language, not the deprecated UnityScript language, so I've removed the `[unityscript]` tags. Please ensure you read the tag descriptions before using them so as not to misuse tags in future.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't happen?

Comment: When I play a game and win a 1 point, it adds this 1 point but then if I play again it will save another score, excluding that 1.

Comment: `totalScore = GameController.score++;` - are you intentionally storing the *old* value of `score` in `totalScore`? Or did you forget how post-increment works?

Comment: Yes I'm storing the previous value and I want to add it to the current value but it doesn't happen

Answer (score 0):

Why is the `GameController.score` completely detached from this? I would expect you rather do

```
// actually load the previous score into GameController.score
GameController.score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("lastScore", GameController.score);
// then AFTER this update the text
YellowSquare.GetComponent<Text>().text = GameController.score.ToString();
```

.. and then in `Update` rather do

```
// Btw do you really want your score to be a counter of how many FRAMES you have played? o.O
GameController.score++;

PlayerPrefs.SetInt("lastScore", GameController.score);
// also update the text after changing the value
YellowSquare.GetComponent<Text>().text = GameController.score.ToString();
```

Comment: i have an object in my game that every time i pick it up it gives me 1 point so these points are saved as in-game currency. When I use `GameController++;` on `Update` it adds numbers every frame but that's not what I want, I don't know if I did it wrong but it didn't work.

Comment: Well what **do** you want to happen exactly?

Comment: I want that when I am finished the game, the points that I received in the score be placed in a UI where it counts the coins and adds with the previous coins, in my code I already managed to make the score appear in the UI but it shows the score of each match and does not add up the points obtained